# Inno Script Studio Hangs Indefinitely When Clicking the Compile Button

Tags: windows, inno-setup, windows-7-x64

I'm having a recurring issue on Windows 7 whereby on clicking the compile button in Inno Script Studio version 2.2.2.32 the application hangs indefinitely and refuses to respond. After end tasking and restarting the software the problem persists and it is only rectified on a restart of the operating system.

The problem seems to be an issue whereby the previously compiled Inno Setup executable cannot be overwritten by the newer version of the file.

Attempting to manually delete the file in file explorer results in the following dialog appearing but never completing:

[image]

Attempting the same through the command line results in a command that never terminates.

This appears to happen only when an installation is terminated prematurely usually because the script has encountered an error. On inspection of the file it has no ownership or permissions set. It does not seem to be related to Anti-Virus software as far as I can tell because I've disabled all the Sophos services I can see in the SCM.

Anybody have this issue before?

Comment: Did you try to turn off an antivirus?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as I'm on a company network. I've terminated all processes in task manager bar the following: crss.exe, dwm.exe, explorer.exe, nvvsvc.exe, NvXDSync.exe, winlogon.exe and wuauclt.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Try to workaround the issue by using an unique output filename for each compilation.

You can use:

```
[Setup]
OutputBaseFilename=setup-{#GetDateTimeString('yyyy-mm-dd-hh-nn-ss', '', '')}
```

Comment: Thanks am doing something similar at the moment but each file is almost a gigabyte so it is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Can you delete the file normally? (not to recycle bin) E.g. using `del` command?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The del command run from the command line never completes (it just hangs).

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen with another IDE?

I mean classic Compile32.exe (default Inno Setup IDE) or Visual & Installer for Microsoft Visual Studio or RAD & Installer for Embarcadero RAD Studio?

This could be IDE related thing or Windows so we need to eliminate them one by one.